# Solving a differential equation with trigonometric terms for both numerator and denominator of derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the below equation to obtain $\theta$ as a function of $t$.

> $A \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = B\sin (Ct) - D \sin\theta$

Note that $\theta$ can be expected to vary continuously as a function of $t$ (this is a model of a physical system, namely a pendulum with additional forces), but the relation between the two or even the NATURE of this relation is presently not known.

A,B,C,D are just constants. The only boundary condition is $\theta = 0$ at $t=0$, which doesn't help much.

I began with naive manipulation of the LHS/RHS to integrate the terms wrt $d\theta$ and $dt$ as appropriate

> $A\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + D\sin\theta = B\sin(Ct)$
>
> $A\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}.\frac{d\theta}{dt}.dt + D\sin\theta.d\theta = B\sin(Ct).\frac{d\theta}{dt}dt$

Integrating the above:

> $A.\theta . \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} +  A(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2 - D\cos\theta =  B(- \frac{\cos(Ct)}{C}.\frac{d\theta}{dt} + \sin(Ct).\theta) + const $
>
> $\theta . (A\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} - B\sin(Ct)) +  \frac{d\theta}{dt}.(A\frac{d\theta}{dt} + \frac{B}{C}\cos(Ct)) = D\cos\theta + const  $

This only made it more complicated, with no reduction in the number of terms.

I'd also considered a Taylor series but eventually run into the same problem of added complexity with no further insight to the solution.

Perhaps either approach was hopelessly naive or needlessly complicated in its thinking. Perhaps there are standard methods to solve equations of this form that I'm not aware of - I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: can you assume that $\sin(\theta(t))\approx \theta(t)?$

Comment: I'm trying to arrive at generalizable conclusions about the system in question, so I'd greatly prefer not to (though I'm aware that the $\sin\theta$ assumption is commonly used for solving pendulum-motion equations). Perhaps as a last resort?

Comment: A Fourier series expansion of $\theta$ wrt $t$ won't help either - I just end up with more terms. What am I doing wrong? It should be possible to predict the behavior of a system given the controlling forces and basic laws of interaction correct? The methods used so far maybe naive but there should be something?